# How to power ESP32 Using Battery

Tags: arduino, esp32

Currently making a project using ESP32. I just want to know that how can I use ESP32 without USB plugin in to laptop/PC. How to do it using Battery?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Maybe take a look at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ESP32 development boards available. Which one do you own ?

Most common solutions to power your ESP32 are:

1. Via the USB port.
2. Using unregulated voltage between 5V and 12V, connected to the 5V and GND pins. This voltage is regulated on-board.
3. Using regulated 3.3V voltage, connected to the 3.3V and GND pins*

*By using the 3.3v pin you must be extra careful and not exceed the 3.3V limit, or your ESP32 module will be damaged.

Comment: 12 V to 5 V pins?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using rechargeable lithium batteries like 18650 or other 5V accu packs.
I use in this case a power bank. But be aware, wifi decreses the lifetime enormous.